# Rotating kinematic body to keep it aligned with sprite

Tags: rotation, libgdx

In my project, I have a body which I have declared as kinematic body.Its associated to a cannon sprite
Game play is such that user can rotate cannon by drag.I calculate the rotation angle and rotate the cannon sprite accordingly.
But I am not able to figure out how to rotate the body so that it remains aligned with cannon sprite.

With regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use `body.setTransform(float x, float y, float angle)` or `body.setTransform(Vector2 position, float angle)` to manually set the rotation of the body. Note that the angle variable must be in radians, so a call to `MathUtils.degreesToRadians` might be necessary. For the position parameter(s), you can just use the body's existing position (`body.getPosition()`).

Edit: When you are rotating your body, I am pretty sure the origin will be at the centre of gravity. I assume when you are rotating your cannon, the origin is not at the centre. To avoid odd rotation behaviour, when you are initializing your cannon's shape, you can call `polygonShape.setAsBox(float halfWidth, float halfHeight, Vector2 centre, float angle)`. The `Vector2 centre` allows you to manually change the centre of the body around which I assume it rotates.